# Is there any free or open offline satellite/aerial imagery for commercial use?

Tags: tiles, imagery, maps, offline, commercial

I'm developing a product for offline use in Brazil in rural areas where there is no Internet connection. I'm searching for a free imagery source which can be used offline in a commercial product.

ESRI and mapQuestOpen are free but their agreements only allow online use.

Is there any free or open offline satellite/aerial imagery for commercial use?

Comment: What resolution do you need?  Is Landsat 8 too coarse?

Comment: 8 is good enough. But 10 will be great. for some Brazilian regions.

Comment: you can download Landsat8 in bundles from https://libra.developmentseed.org/ (check cloud levels over latest images) license is CCv3.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

Comment: Landsat 8 = 30m resolution I believe.

Comment: I would like to some offline tiles data. 
I'm using OpenLayers3. it will be very easy to integrate with any tile provider, or offline tiles. Libra provides-me some raw data. it mus be processed in order to be integrated with another tools.

Comment: I was looking into this as well, and have found GMapCatcher. It works very well, and if you need it for an area offline, then you can grab all the tiles you need and put them into the tiling program.

Comment: However I just need a free source for commercial use, which allow offline/cached use.

Comment: @Martin I would bet that GMapCatcher violates the terms of use for many of the APIs it supports.  Even if you're a paying customer to some, their terms may disallow compiling caches to be distributed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for a world map free software for me was NASA blue marble.
http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484.